# Highcharts 3d Pie Data Labels

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

The data labels when using 3d Pie Chart displays in an incorrect manner.

I only have two slices and most of the times, the labels of one slice ends up being in the space of other slice. See http://jsfiddle.net/tn036sak/

I do want to use the distance property so it does not show labels outside of the pie chart.

This is my code -

```
    $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 65,
            beta: 0
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            depth: 35,
            dataLabels: {
            distance:-40,
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
            ['Firefox', 10.0],
            ['Chrome', 90]
        ]
    }]
});
```

});

Please suggest how the labels can be shown on the respective slice.

Comment: Hi, I think this is small Highcharts bug. You can find information about this issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3259
As a workaround I think that you can move your dataLabels with attr() method: http://jsfiddle.net/tn036sak/1/